# JPARepository save methods returns null?

Tags: java, junit, spring-data-jpa, mockito

I want to write tests for service, but it looks like JPARepository.save method returns null.
Here is my code from *ServiceTest*

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

class PatientServiceTest {
@Mock
private PatientRepository patientRepository;
@Spy
private PatientMapper mapper = new PatientMapper();
@InjectMocks
private PatientService serviceUnderTests;

@Test
void whenCreatePatientByService_thenPatientRepositoryIsNotEmpty() {
    PatientModel patientModel = new PatientModel(134, "Pawel", "Nowak", 
    "pawel@test.pl", "123456789");
    serviceUnderTests.create(patientModel);

    assertNotNull(patientRepository.findAll());
}
```

*Service* code

```
public PatientModel create(PatientModel patientModel) {
    PatientEntity patientEntity = mapper.from(patientModel);

    PatientEntity savedPatient = repository.save(patientEntity);
    return mapper.from(savedPatient);
}
```

Here is a screenshot from debugging mode:

[image]

Repository is just interface extends JPARepository, and mapper has only two methods which map Entity to Model and Model to Entity.

IntelliJ says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.nowakpawel.healthcenter.repository.entity.PatientEntity.getId()" because "entity" is null

    at com.nowakpawel.healthcenter.service.mapper.PatientMapper.from(PatientMapper.java:24)
    at com.nowakpawel.healthcenter.service.PatientService.create(PatientService.java:29)
    at com.nowakpawel.healthcenter.service.PatientServiceTest.whenCreatePatientByService_thenPatientRepositoryIsNotEmpty(PatientServiceTest.java:44)
```

Why when I want to map Entity to Model in *Service*, Java put *null* into *from* method, while *PatientEntity* isn't null?

Comment: The service under test calls the `patientRepository` mock. In the code shown, the mock is not configured to return anything, hence it returns `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*PatientModel* is passed as parameter to the method and it is converted into *PatientEntity patientEntity* object. As its a unit test and the PatientRepository has been mocked, so when something is mocked you need to return the value of the mock.
So value should be returned for the statement

```
PatientEntity savedPatient = repository.save(patientEntity);
```

You can write the test case in this way

```
void whenCreatePatientByService_thenPatientRepositoryIsNotEmpty() {
    PatientModel patientModel = new PatientModel(134, "Pawel", "Nowak", 
    "pawel@test.pl", "123456789");
    PatientEntity patientEntity = new PatientEntity();
    patientEntity.setXxxx("Nowak"); // Other values as per getter and setters

    doReturn(patientEntity).when(patientRepository).save(Matchers.any());
    
    PatientModel response = serviceUnderTests.create(patientModel);        
    
    assertNotNull(response);
    asserEquals("Nowak", response.getXxxxx()); //Getter method name here    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for answering my question. I have missed that part of Mockito ;)
But I still have trouble. Here is my code now:

```
@Test
    void whenCreatePatientByService_thenPatientRepositoryIsNotEmpty() {
        PatientModel patientModel = new PatientModel(14, "Pawel", "Nowak", "pawel@test.pl",
                "123456789");
    
    PatientEntity entity = mapper.from(patientModel);
    when(patientRepository.save(entity)).thenReturn(entity);
    serviceUnderTests.create(patientModel);
    assertNotNull(patientRepository.findAll());
}
```

and got an error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'save' method:
    patientRepository.save(
    PatientEntity [id=14, firstName='Pawel', lastName='Nowak', emailAddress='pawel@test.pl', phoneNumber='123456789']
);
-> at com.nowakpawel.healthcenter.service.PatientService.create(PatientService.java:28)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. patientRepository.save(
    PatientEntity [id=14, firstName='Pawel', lastName='Nowak', emailAddress='pawel@test.pl', phoneNumber='123456789']
);
      -> at com.nowakpawel.healthcenter.service.PatientServiceTest.whenCreatePatientByService_thenPatientRepositoryIsNotEmpty(PatientServiceTest.java:48)
Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
However, there are legit scenarios when this exception generates false negative signal:
  - stubbing the same method multiple times using 'given().will()' or 'when().then()' API
    Please use 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' API for stubbing.
  - stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test
    Please use default or 'silent' JUnit Rule (equivalent of Strictness.LENIENT).
For more information see javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class.
```

As far as I understand - the problem is

> stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test

Am I right? And why this is an error, while I passed Entity to *repository* save method?

Here is my whole project in case it's needed -> https://github.com/nowakpawel/health-center

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. Just added `equals` and `hashCode` methods to `patientEntity`.

Please close this thread as it is solved.